# Match variable to JSON content and return data

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that contains a country name.

```
var country = 'belgium';
```

I have a JS data structure:

```
var countryCoords = {
  argentina: '56 100',
  belgium: '100 200'
}
```

How do I get the co-ordinates for Belgium?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects support bracket notation and dot notation...

```
var country = 'belgium';

var countryCoords = {
  argentina: '56 100',
  belgium: '100 200'
}

countryCoords[country]; // '100 200'
countryCoords.belgium; // '100 200'
```

Comment: See? Really, really simple and yet my mind couldn't get it! Thanks Kyle, you got there first.

Comment: you're welcome. Please throw @dystroy a bone, with an upvote, as I believe he answered at the same time as me.

Comment: I answered first. But if Kyle is clearer, there is no problem at all in accepting his answer. The goal here was to explain ;)

Comment: I don't know how to look at timestamps with greater precision than minutes... If there is a way, please advise.

Comment: Two ways : 1) use the "oldest" tab. 2) pass the mouse over the date. You'll see there was a gigantic difference of 3 whole seconds ! ;)

Comment: Yeah, sorry dystoy you were fastest but as you say Kyle is a bit clearer! Upvoted you both, and many thanks for helping jog my memory!

Answer (score 3):

you get them with

```
var coords = countryCoords[country];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract them using `country` as the key:

```
console.log(countryCoords[country]);
```